# what type should i specify for lambda expression in method call

Tags: c#, lambda, method-call

See this small code and tell me what type should I use in method call

```
Method((i => i>7));

    public void Method(which type should I specify here?)
    {
    // some stuff
    }
```

Comment: **Which language?** It looks like C#, but do we really have to guess?

Comment: I'm going to guess C#, since it looks like it.

Comment: yes, its C# language...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that the type is `Func<int, bool>`. Also, the additional parenthesis around the lambda are useless.

Comment: thans... how I get data from variable like:                    Public void Method(Func<int, bool> filter){ how I get data from filter variable? }

Comment: How I play with filter parameter. I want to Find out how many items that satisfy (pass) the filter and write the number to the console

Comment: @SPBeginer You are not passing 'data', you are passing a 'function that takes an int and returns a boolean value'. What do you want to do with the function, apart from invoking it with, for example `filter.Invoke(10);`?